# Ruby: Deleting rows of 2D array with a leading "zero"

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to Ruby language and have been playing with it recently. However, when I am trying to delete the last two rows of a 2D array:

```
array2d = [["a", "b", "c"],[0],[3, 2, 1],[0],[5,6,7]]
```

Ruby somehow deleted second row for me. When I try to store the zero in second row as string:

```
array2d = [["a", "b", "c"],["0"],[3, 2, 1],[0],[5,6,7]]
```

Ruby does not delete the "zero row".

Is there any special mechanism that Ruby treats zero? Is Ruby consider array with "0" integer as empty?
Here is the whole code that I wrote:

```
array2d = [["a", "b", "c"],[0],[3, 2, 1],[0],[5,6,7]]

array2d.each do |row|
    print "["
    row.each do |cell|
        print cell.to_s + ","
    end
    puts "]"
end


last=4
last.downto(3) do |i|
    row = array2d[i]
    row.each_with_index do |cell, j|
        puts "array2d[" + i.to_s + "][" + j.to_s + "] = " + cell.to_s
    end
    array2d.delete(row)
end

array2d.each do |row|
    print "["
    row.each do |cell|
        print cell.to_s + ","
    end
    puts "]"
end
```

Comment: Your code appears to delete the last two rows just fine. It's really difficult to tell what you're trying to ask. No, there is no "special mechanism" by which Ruby treats `0`. `0` is `0`, and `"0"` is `"0"`, and they are completely different.

Comment: Oh I modified the code back to when it has the error. Can you please try the code again? Anyway, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking `array2d.delete([0])`. That deletes **all** instances of `[0]`. Ruby can't tell which one you want to delete and which one you don't, especially since you're not even trying to delete the *first* instance. How would Ruby know you want to delete the *last* instance only?

If you want to remove a row from a multi-dimensional array, use thw row's index with `delete_at`.

```
last = 4
last.downto(3) do |i|
    # ...
    array2d.delete_at(i)
end
```